# ¿Existe una palabra que signifique "la cualidad de ser azul"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Según la RAE, rojez es "la cualidad de ser rojo" [Rojez](https://dle.rae.es/rojez) y amarillez "la cualidad de ser amarillo" [Amarillez](https://dle.rae.es/amarillez). Para el color verde entiendo que la palabra es verdor (o verdura). Para el blanco y negro es blancura y negrura.

¿Y para el azul? ¿Existe una palabra que signifique "la cualidad de ser azul"?

Comment: En el libro Principios de color y holopintura de Antonio Valero Muñoz dice: atributos incompatibles: amarillez,  azulez, verdor y rojez. Aunque nunca los he escuchado(pero sí leído algunos) salvo verdor, pero este último usado como sustantivo y como adjetivo similar a azulado, azulino, verdoso. Para indicar la cualidad de ser azul con una palabra es necesario de un contexto y de la connotación que la circunscriba a un ámbito determinado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aunque no aparece en el diccionario, algunos usan el término "azulidad". Por ejemplo, en [este artículo de "La Nación](https://www.lanacion.com.ar/lifestyle/azul-profundo-nid2162684/), un importante periódico de Argentina (tal vez el de redacción más cuidada), encontramos esta oración:

- Tan intenso es este color que en el siglo XVIII hasta se desarrolló un "cianómetro", un invento del suizo Horace de Saussure para medir la **azulidad** del cielo.

Comment: No figura en ningún diccionario, a un autor le sale decir azulez y a otro azulidad. Si me saldría decirle azulura sería distinto en algo a lo que ellos hacen?

Comment: @Pablo No hay límites para la productividad de la lengua, más allá de los que imponga la morfología. "azulidad" aparece bastante -- no así "azulez" o "azulura". (Nota: Se debe decir "si me saliera", no "si me saldría).

Comment: Aquí hay algunos ejemplos de uso de "azulidad": https://apps.rae.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_A/LETRA_A_PDF/AZULIDAD.

Answer (score 1):

He visto este texto, que me pareció curioso:

“El color de la sangre varía dependiendo de cuan saturada de oxígeno se encuentra, debido a las propiedades ópticas del grupo *heme* de la molécula de hemoglobina. Cuando la molécula de hemoglobina libera oxígeno, pierde su color rosado, adquiriendo un tono más azulado y deja pasar menos la luz roja.
 
Así, el oxímetro de pulso determina la saturación de oxígeno midiendo espectrofotométricamente el grado de “azulez” de la sangre arterial y expresa esta "azulez" en términos de saturación.”

Pienso que “azulidad” sería un mejor candidato a la aprobación oficial, más que “azulez”.